# JPA2 - Getting child entities of joined entities recursively using Criteria API as Dynamic Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I want to understand how to apply certain conditions using Criteria API instead of JPQL, particularly if Criteria can be used to recursively get child entities from Joins in the same way that JPQL can, through Join hierarchies.

**UPDATE**

The comments from Tiny and Chris prompted me to first be clear what i'm trying to achieve:

My example has 4 entities as per the below diagram. Enitemshas a ManyToOne relationship with Ensources. Entopics has OneToMany relationship with Enitems. Entopics has a OneToMany relationship with SegmentsNew.

[image]

I am building a search page where the user can find a chosen item by entering as many or as little in the search criteria. In the below example a search for "Corporate Law" should return all the items in the Corporate Law segment (even if nothing else is entered).

[image]

My entities:

Enitems:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "enitem")

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "itemid")
private Integer itemid;
@Size(max = 500)
@Column(name = "itemname")
private String itemname;
@Column(name = "daterec")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date daterec;
@Lob
@Size(max = 65535)
@Column(name = "itemdetails")
private String itemdetails;
private String enteredby;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "items")
private Collection<Endatamaster> endatamasterCollection;
@JoinColumn(name = "topicid", referencedColumnName = "topicid")
@ManyToOne
private Entopic topics;
@JoinColumn(name = "sourceid", referencedColumnName = "sourceid")
@ManyToOne
private Ensource source;
```

Entopics:

```
public class Entopic implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "topicid")
private Integer topicid;
@Size(max = 500)
@Column(name = "topicname")
private String topicname;
@Size(max = 500)
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
@Column(name = "locksec")
private boolean locksec;
@JoinColumn(name = "segmentid", referencedColumnName = "SEGMENTID")
@ManyToOne
private Segmentnew segments;
@JoinColumn(name = "marketid", referencedColumnName = "marketid")
@ManyToOne
private Enmarkets markets;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "topics")
private Collection<Enitem> enitemCollection;
```

Ensource:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ensource")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Ensource.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Ensource e")})
public class Ensource implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "sourceid")
private Integer sourceid;
@Size(max = 500)
@Column(name = "sourcename")
private String sourcename;
@Size(max = 500)
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@JoinColumn(name = "typeid", referencedColumnName = "typeid")
@ManyToOne
private Enitemtype entype;
```

Segmentsnew:

```
public class Segmentnew implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "SEGMENTID")
private Integer segmentid;
@Size(max = 255)
@Column(name = "SEGMENTNAME")
private String segmentname;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "segments")
private Collection<Entopic> entopicCollection;
@JoinColumn(name = "sectorId", referencedColumnName = "SECTORID")
@ManyToOne
private Sectorsnew sectors;
```

A desired JPQL string representation of this would be:

```
Select e FROM Enitems e WHERE e.topics.topicid = :topicid 
AND e.source.sourceid = :sourceid; AND e.topics.segments.segmentid = :segmentid
```

Search page uses JSf Primefaces:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <p:outputLabel value="Sectors: "/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{sectorBean.sectorid}"
                                     filter="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="NULL"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{sectorBean.secList}"
                                       var="sect"
                                       itemLabel="#{sect.sectorname}"
                                       itemValue="#{sect.sectorid}"/>
                        <f:ajax listener="#{segmentsBean.segFromSec}" render="segs"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Segments: "/>
                    <p:panel id="segs">

                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{queryBean.segmentid}"
                                         rendered="#{not empty segmentsBean.menuNormList}">

                            <f:selectItems value="#{segmentsBean.menuNormList}"
                                           var="segs"
                                           itemLabel="#{segs.segmentname}"
                                           itemValue="#{segs.segmentid}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                    </p:panel>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Topics: "/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{queryBean.topicid}" filter="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="NULL"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{clienTopicBean.publicTopMenu}"
                                       var="pubs"
                                       itemLabel="#{pubs.topicname}"
                                       itemValue="#{pubs.topicid}"/>


                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Type: "/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{typeBean.typeid}" filter="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="NULL"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{typeBean.menuList}"
                                       var="type"
                                       itemLabel="#{type.typename}"
                                       itemValue="#{type.typeid}"/>

                        <f:ajax listener="#{sourceBean.sourceFromType}" render="src"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Sources: "/>
                    <p:panel id="src">

                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{queryBean.sourceid}"
                                         rendered="#{not empty sourceBean.sourceListNorm}">

                            <f:selectItems value="#{sourceBean.sourceListNorm}"
                                           var="srcs"
                                           itemLabel="#{srcs.sourcename}"
                                           itemValue="#{srcs.sourceid}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                    </p:panel>
                </p:panelGrid>
```

This is what I'm trying using CAPI:

```
public List<Enitem> superQ(Integer topicid, Integer sourceid,
        Integer segmentid) {
    em.clear();

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(Enitem.class);
    Root<Enitem> rt = cq.from(Enitem.class);

    cq.select(rt);
    cq.distinct(true);

    List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    Predicate whereClause = cb.conjunction();
    // if () {
    Path<Entopic> topJoin = rt.get("topics");


    if (topicid != 0) {

        ParameterExpression<Integer> p
                = cb.parameter(Integer.class, "topicid");
        whereClause = cb.and(whereClause, cb.equal(topJoin.get("topicid"), p));
    }
    if (segmentid != 0) {

        ParameterExpression<Integer> p
                = cb.parameter(Integer.class, "segmentid");
        whereClause = cb.and(whereClause, cb.equal(topJoin.get("segments").get("segmentid"), p));
    }
    //}

    if (sourceid != 0) {
        ParameterExpression<Integer> p
                = cb.parameter(Integer.class, "sourceid");
        whereClause = cb.and(whereClause, cb.equal(rt.get("source").get("sourceid"), p));
    }

//    if(whereClause.getExpressions().isEmpty()) {
//        throw new RuntimeException("no criteria");
//    }
    cq.where(whereClause);

    TypedQuery q = em.createQuery(cq);
    if (topicid != 0) {
        q.setParameter("topicid", topicid);
    }
    if (segmentid != 0) {
        q.setParameter("segmentid", segmentid);
    }

    if (sourceid != 0) {
        q.setParameter("sourceid", sourceid);
    }

    return q.getResultList();

}
```

**It is important to state if(entityName != 0) rather than if(entityName != null), which I was previously doing and this caused the application to require all parameters to be populated by the user. This is probably because integer value of null is actually the number zero?**

The generated SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.itemid, t1.daterec, t1.ENTEREDBY, t1.itemdetails, t1.itemname, 
t1.sourceid, t1.topicid FROM enitem t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN entopic t0 ON (t0.topicid 
= t1.topicid) LEFT OUTER JOIN ensource t2 ON (t2.sourceid = t1.sourceid) WHERE 
(((t0.topicid = ?) AND (t2.sourceid = ?)) AND (t0.segmentid = ?))
```

The application is behaving dynamically in that the user only needs to enter any single value in the search page and a list is returned corresponding to that value. **The problem I'm now having is that the same results are being returned if I do a second query even though I already cleared the EntityManager at the start of the method. SO the application only works if it's restarted. Do I need to refersh the entities?**

Comment: "*Is the above correct in using the Join between `Entopics`, `Ensource`, `Segmentsnew` to get the related items in a List of type `Enitems`?*" Is this the only real question? You can confirm this by looking closely into the generated SQL statement. Do it persistently for every query you formulate using criteria or JPQL. (By the way, two `Root` are not needed. You probably already know that `Join` can be chained recursively. It depends upon the functional requirement of your project).

Comment: Thank you and sorry if I'm not clear. No it is not the only question. My question is actually how to recursively chain in Criteria Api a d if the same 'entity.subentity.object' syntax is used as in JPQL?  I edited the question and clarified further what I want

Comment: You are still not clearly showing what you want, and from the exception, it states that enitems does not have a 'topics' attribute defined.  Criteria can be formed from almost any JPQL statement, so maybe show your JPQL query if you have it.  Using "nameOfJoin.source" is equivalent to using nameOfJoin.get("source") for example, so "nameOfJoin.source.sourceid = :sourceid" might be qb.equal(nameOfJoin.get("source").get("sourceid"), cb.parameter(Integer.class, "sourceid"))

Comment: Thanks Chris. The exception was just me being careless and not understanding the entity relationships. I fixed this now and updated the question with more details about what I'm trying to achieve. I thought my problem is in the way i am getting the segmentid. Maybe it is because I'm using two roots, which Tiny explained was not necessary, but I can't figure out how to get the segmentid from the Enitems root (which produces the IllegalArgumentException). Other than that I'm not sure why the query is not responding dynamically.

Comment: We don't have the entities, so its hard to tell you what is right or wrong with what you have.  Tiny already mentioned you don't need a second root, but your update still has you obtaining and trying to use rtc instead of the sourceJoin to get segjoin.  Check the SQL that is generated and you'll see the result of what you are doing.  As mentioned, I find it easier to write out the product I want in JPQL, execute it to be sure it is what I want, and then write the matching criteria query.

Comment: I updated the question include the generated SQL and I'm following Tiny's advice and sticking to a single root. I can include the entities, but I'm trying to figure out a solution without introducing too much code. If the SQL log doesn't help I can include the entities. Thank you

Comment: The only difference I see in your SQL and the JPQL is that you don't seem to want to use the left joins.  "e.topics" forces an inner join into the SQL, while your use of 'left' in the rt.join("topics", JoinType.LEFT); forces the criteria query to use a left outer join.  You should just use a 'get' in the criteria query if/when needed, assuming you only want the join if the segmentid or topicid are passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the logic of the JPA was correct but the problem is in the web framework which means i have to adapt my JPA accordingly. JSF doesn't accept 'null' as a definition of an integer in the search page and only accepts a numerical value or just "". Changing the if statement from :

```
if(entity != null);
```

to

```
if(entity != 0);
```

resulted in the application behaving as expected. This solves the problem in this question. Thanks to Chris and Tiny for their help

Answer (score 1):

Using From and join both give you objects that can be cast to the root interface allowing joins to be chained.
Try something like:

```
public List<Enitem> superQ(Integer topicid, Integer sourceid,
      Integer segmentid) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(Enitem.class);
    Root<Enitem> rt = cq.from(Enitem.class);

    cq.select(rt);
    cq.distinct(true);

    List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    Predicate whereClause = cb.conjunction();
    if ((topicid != null)||(segmentid != null)){
      Path<Entopic> topJoin =rt.get("topics");
      if(topicid != null) {
          ParameterExpression<Integer> p =
                  cb.parameter(Integer.class, "topicid");
          whereClause = cb.and(whereClause, cb.equal(topJoin.get("topicid"), p));
      }
      if(segmentid != null) {
        ParameterExpression<Integer> p =
                cb.parameter(Integer.class, "segmentid");
        whereClause = cb.and(whereClause, cb.equal(topJoin.get("segments").get("segmentid"), p));
      }
    }

    if(sourceid != null) {
      ParameterExpression<Integer> p =
               cb.parameter(Integer.class, "sourceid");
      whereClause = cb.and(whereClause, cb.equal(rt.get("source").get("sourceid"), p));
    }


    if(whereClause.getExpressions().isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("no criteria");
    }
    cq.where(whereClause);
}
```

This will produce something without any joining unless parameters that require a join are specified, and will use inner joins as the provided JPQL would.

Comment: You have if (){ in the above code which produces a compile time error. Should there be an argument there or is the statement a typo?

Comment: I forgot the (topicid != null)||(segmentid != null) as it was done quickly in the browser

Comment: You can probably remove that (topicid != null)||(segmentid != null) check, as the rt.get("topics") might be safe call if the topic/segment ids aren't needed - I recall it may only force a join if it gets used in the query.

Comment: I tried it with and without that statement. Unfortunately it behaves the same way as my original query requiring all parameters to be entered. I also added the entities in the update to the question. If there's no obvious answer why the query isn't behaving dynamically I'll take your advice and go back to the drawing board by rewriting in JPQL

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your behavior problem.  What SQL do you get if you don't have all parameters?  Give a concrete example of what is wrong and I can help you fix it

Comment: Could it be the topics join being reused?  If so, move the rt.get("topics") part into each and clause so that a new one is generated rather then both clauses using the same join.

Comment: Say I am searching an item which has a source called 'John'. I select 'John' from the drop down menu next to the Source tab in the search page. I expect it to return  a list of ALL items with a source of John. But if I leave any of the search fields blank in the above, te query returns no records. In that way it's not dynamic since the user has to explicitly define all query parameters instead of just being able to search based on a single parameter. Does that make sense?

Comment: I tried your suggestion to declare the join in every clause but this didn't help. What is finally making things work is that i changed the if statements from if(entity != null) to if(entity !=0) and this is making things behave better, as updated in the question. The problem now is how to refresh the query. I'm not sure if I need to refresh each entity , close the em or what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99968/discussion-between-jay-tai-and-chris).